# SAS convert string into datetime

Tags: datetime, casting, sas

I have a column in a table of string representing datetime like `"01-Oct-2012 12:23:43.324"` how can I cast this in a SAS `datetime` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DATETIME informat will read that string

```
new_var=input(datestring,datetime24.);
format new_var datetime24.;
```

Comment: If you format the new variable as `datetime24.3` it will display the fractional seconds.  Otherwise it truncates.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a single informat which will read that format of datetime... so split it into the date & time components then use the dhms function to create a datetime value.

```
data have ;
  datestring = "01-Oct-2012 12:23:43.324" ;
run ;

data want ;
  set have ;

  dt = input(scan(datestring,1,' '),??date11.) ;
  tm = input(scan(datestring,2,' '),??time14.) ;
  dttm = dhms(dt,0,0,tm) ;

  format dt date9. tm time14.3 dttm datetime24.3 ;
run ;
```

Comment: when I see how many lines it takes, no wonder why people drop SAS